# Creating a new object by taking some of the element from existing Object

Tags: javascript, json, object

A little background, I post to PayPal's API from within an Angular 6 component and receive the following error:

```
Error: Request to post https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment failed with 400 error. Correlation id: c4d516c6ef58b, c4d516c6ef58b

{
    "name": "VALIDATION_ERROR",
    "details": [
        {
            "field": "transactions.item_list.items.category",
            "issue": "Cannot construct instance of `com.paypal.platform.payments.model.rest.types.ItemCategory`, problem: oils is invalid value. Supported values are PHYSICAL, DIGITAL"
        }
    ],
    "message": "Invalid request - see details",
    "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors",
    "debug_id": "c4d516c6ef58b"
```

This is because my JSON has an element named "category" but it's value is not "PHYSICAL" or "DIGITAL"

As a result, I need to make a new object that has elements that PayPal can accept - id will become sku, name can remain name, price can remain price, counter will become quantity and description will remain description.

With that said, the JSON object that I am receiving has many more elements than just the five listed. I have tried to make another object in the following ways, but I have received varying errors, from cart is undefined to .map is not a function:

```
this.product = this.shoppingCartObj.cart.products.product;
const Obj = this.product;
const countRows = Object.keys(Obj).map(function(key) {
  return [Number(key), Obj[key]];
});

for (let b = 0; b < countRows.length; b++) {
  this.copyShoppingCartObj.cart.products.product[
    b
  ].sku = this.shoppingCartObj.cart.products.product[b].id;
  this.copyShoppingCartObj.cart.products.product[
    b
  ].name = this.shoppingCartObj.cart.products.product[b].name;
  this.copyShoppingCartObj.cart.products.product[
    b
  ].quantity = this.shoppingCartObj.cart.products.product[b].counter;
  this.copyShoppingCartObj.cart.products.product[
    b
  ].price = this.shoppingCartObj.cart.products.product[b].price;
  this.copyShoppingCartObj.cart.products.product[
    b
  ].description = this.shoppingCartObj.cart.products.product[b].description;
  this.ar.push(this.product[b]);
}
this.product = this.copyShoppingCartObj.cart.products.product;
```

To:

```
this.copyShoppingCartObj = this.shoppingCartObj.map(data => ({
  sku: data.cart.products.product.id,
  name: data.cart.products.product.name,
  quantity: data.cart.products.product.counter,
  price: data.cart.products.product.price,
  description: data.cart.products.product.description
}));
```

And - "this.shoppingCartObj.forEach is not a function"

```
 this.shoppingCartObj.forEach(function(data) {
  const newMap = {};
  newMap.cart.products.product.sku = data.cart.products.product.id;
  newMap.cart.products.product.name = data.cart.products.product.name;
  newMap.cart.products.product.quantity =
    data.cart.products.product.counter;
  newMap.cart.products.product.price = data.cart.products.product.price;
  newMap.cart.products.product.description =
    data.cart.products.product.description;
  this.copyShoppingCartObj.push(newMap);
});
```

The following is and example of what the JSON looks like:

```
[{
  "id": "8",
  "name": "Austin to Carls 32 to 33 chocolates to oil",
  "price": "9.67",
  "category": "oils",
  "description": "The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Section 1.10.32 of de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum, written by Cicero in 45 BC Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur ? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur",
  "ts": "2019-01-08 11:47:09",
  "product_image_id": "33",
  "enabled": "1",
  "product_image": "crater-winslow-40.png",
  "counter": 3
}, {
  "id": "9",
  "name": "something test 3 upd",
  "price": "12.23",
  "category": "chocolates",
  "description": "The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Section 1.10.32 of de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum, written by Cicero in 45 BC Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur ? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur",
  "ts": "2019-01-08 08:54:49",
  "product_image_id": "29",
  "enabled": "1",
  "product_image": "40-64-grand-canyon.png",
  "counter": 2
}]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `map` through array of object and using `destructer` get the `desired key's value` and return them as Object as per your `key value` pair need.

```js
let obj = [{"id": "8","name": "Austin to Carls 32 to 33 chocolates to oil","price": "9.67","category": "oils",  "description": "The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore e", "ts": "2019-01-08 11:47:09", "product_image_id": "33", "enabled": "1","product_image": "crater-winslow-40.png", "counter": 3}, {"id": "9","name": "something test 3 upd","price": "12.23","category": "chocolates","description": "The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididu", "ts": "2019-01-08 08:54:49", "product_image_id": "29", "enabled": "1", "product_image": "40-64-grand-canyon.png","counter": 2}]

let op = obj.map(e=>{
  let {counter,id,name,price,description} = e;
  return{
    name,price,description,
    quantity: counter,
    sku: id,
  }
})

console.log(op)
```

Comment: thank you for replying and thank you for the correct answer